# Stylesheet not linking to html

Tags: html, css

[work.css property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6znxl.png)   [folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1EXm.png)I'm using Windows 8.1, wamp, sublime  (not registered), and Firefox.
 I was following some tutorials on html5 and css3.
The first project went smoothly, I still keep its folder in c:windows/wamp/www, and all is well.
However, I started a new tutorial on html tables and thought to make a new folder/project. In this new folder/project I could not get the stylesheet to customize the html index, so
I scrapped it. I started over, only to have the same issue.

I've tried creating multiple projects now, tested them on multiple browsers, and even installed mamp. But the problem persist.

Clicking the css option in firefox/fire bug shows the stylesheet.

My files are in the same folder, index.html work.css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="work.css">
</head>
<body> why wont you work

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share your html head tag Code.

Comment: Try to remove the leading `/` from `work.css`, to it becomes `href="work.css"`.

Comment: Ive tried that, but still it wont link.

Comment: Are you serving these files from a local server? Check the network tab for any 404s on the Css.

Comment: Im running a local host on wamp. How do i check the network tab for 404s?

Comment: Write new question for it. Note: searching ans on web carefully then ask new question in StackOverflow If you don't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CSS and HTML file in same folder then

```
<link href="work.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If your CSS file in different folder then

```
<link href="css/work.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Note: HTML doesn't required `../` for linking any files. `../` It will required when you call any files by CSS code.

**Edited:**

I seen your image. You haven't create any CSS files. Your `work` file is now `work.txt`. Please change it `work.txt` to `work.css`. Please change the windows folder view option details and show the file type.

Comment: Yes same folder, i only added it later.

Comment: @QuandoCalrissian watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgRktKajC0k . I think it will helping you.

Comment: Check you code in FF regular version using firebug. Also clear you browsing history using `CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE`.

Comment: Firefox can see the css.

Comment: please look at the new image, the properties say css

Comment: Open `work.css` file and write `body{background-color: #121212;color: #ffffff;font-size: 30px;margin: 0;padding: 0;text-align: center;}` this code. save it and open it on browser.

Answer (score 0):

if your CSS file is in the same HTML file folder you can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="work.css">
```

but if its in other folder e.g. STYLE folder you have to user this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../STYLE/work.css">
```

Comment: its in the same folder. Ive tried it like this.                                                                                                              <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="work.css">
    </head>
    <body> why wont you work

    </body>
    </html>

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> in chrome and click on the link href if you are able to find css, It should work if you have used class and Id properly otherwise update the css file path in href.